# Appwrite Local Storage Session Issue

Tags: vue.js, session, nuxt.js, local-storage, appwrite

[Appwrite](https://appwrite.io/) is installed in the subdomain. While the site is working in the main domain, it does not save session to localstorage when I login. But if I run it in a different domain, the problem is solved.

It works when Appwrite and my app are in different domains. If it is on the same domain, it does not save "cookieFallback" to localstorage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to update Appwrite. After the update the problem was fixed, I had the same problem.

Comment: Yes, it was fixed after the update. I forgot to write here.

Answer (score 0):

The fallback cookie here is used for overcoming cross-site cookie policies. Sessions should work even if the fallback cookie is not present.